# Linux server: apt-get update "Could not get lock" error

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, google-compute-engine, apt

I have a Google Cloud machine. Every few days, I SSH into the VM and run a handful of commands. Over the past few days, whenever I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following errors:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 2306481 (apt-get)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Please keep in mind that I did not do anything different for the past few weeks and this issue emerged seemingly out of the blue.

After running `ps aux | grep -i apt` to help diagnose the issue, the following is displayed:

```
root     2306449  0.0  0.0   2576   924 ?        Ss   Mar12   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily update
root     2306453  0.0  0.0   2576  1672 ?        S    Mar12   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily lock_is_held update
root     2306481  0.0  0.2  17864 10156 ?        S    Mar12   0:32 apt-get -qq -y update
_apt     2306485  0.0  0.2  21796  8072 ?        S    Mar12   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     2306486  0.0  0.3  25084 11692 ?        S    Mar12   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
_apt     2306487  0.0  0.3  24956 11692 ?        S    Mar12   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
_apt     2306488  0.0  0.2  21796  8024 ?        S    Mar12   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     2306489  0.0  0.2  21796  8076 ?        S    Mar12   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     2306491  0.0  0.1  14968  6132 ?        S    Mar12   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/gpgv
_apt     2307443  0.0  0.1  15836  7020 ?        S    Mar12   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/rred
```

I'm at a loss as to how to get `sudo apt-get update` to work again. I read that killing the process or restarting the machine can result in negative consequences. Please let me know if you'd like any more info.

Comment: Please reboot the system and check whether the "apt-list changes" package is installed while the "unattended-upgrades" feature is being used.

Comment: @djdomi I read that rebooting can cause harm when faced with this issue.

Comment: even an upgrade could be cancled, if you shutdown the progress will stop at a way where you can continue. Update is only fetching the sources from the repo to know whats current inside the  web repo.

Comment: I see - so, what do you mean by "check whether the "apt-list changes" package is installed while the "unattended-upgrades" feature is being used." - how do I do this and why is it important?

Comment: Damit my android did a change on my words, apt-listchanges is blocking the unattended-upgrades, but you just used update which only update the repos lists

Comment: Oh, I see. So, is this something that I don't need to be concerned about or should I check something after rebooting?

Comment: you neither need to take care nor be concerend if a apt update is running.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm kind of hesitant to stop and start the entire VM. Do you know if there's a command I can run that'll just start/stop apt-get or the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stopped then started my VM and it fixed this error. Simple but stressful.

Comment: that is what i said, reboot does good ;)

Answer (score 2):

> root     2306449  0.0  0.0   2576   924 ?        Ss   Mar12   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily update

This is a daily process that updates repositories. Killing it should be fine; a `apt update` should fix lingering issues. Furthermore, wait ten minutes and try again should also work, as `apt update` should not take a terribly long time.

Comment: The problem seems to be with 2306481 (apt-get -qq -y update), not 2306449 (/bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily update). Or, are you saying that the lock on 2306449 (as shown in 2306453) is preventing 2306481 from functioning normally? Also, I have waited days now (which is much longer than 10 minutes) and it's still giving me the same errors.

Comment: `apt-get -qq -y update` is probably called by the other script. As it's only a `update` (e.g. refresh repos) and not `upgrade`, I'd go ahead and kill it.

Comment: What are your thoughts about simply stopping then starting the instance to see if that fixes it? I took a snapshot of the disk and made a new VM based on it so I can see if I can work on a dummy machine but there was no error at all when I tried "update" on that new machine. This makes me think that a simple restart could fix it but I'm not 100% confident in that, especially seeing as some folks faced with a similar issue had problems after rebooting.

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: So, do you think stopping then starting the instance will allow apt-get update to work again?

Comment: Yes, probably, as that will kill the process.